Tomcat: re-deploy war did not clean up static variables?
Tomcat: re-deploy war without server restart did not clean up static variables.
   class Foo {

      static Map<String, Object> cache = new HashMap<>();
   }

After re-deploying a modified war, the cache is not cleaned and keep the old values.
How does the re-deploy work?

does that class live in the WAR file, or in a shared location, like tomcat/lib?

it is inside war.

Is it possible that the class can be found in both locations?
